# Pass data between TableView and another ViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uistoryboardsegue

I am trying to have a list of events presented in a tableView and when the user presses one of the events, it will open another viewController with more information about that particular selection.

This is the `tableView` that has the options that can be selected :

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase

class NewsfeedViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var ref:DatabaseReference!,
        posts = [eventStruct]()
    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
    var propertStruct : (Any)? = nil


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadNews()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func loadNews() {
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        ref.child("events").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let valueDictionary = snapshot.value as? [AnyHashable:String]
            {
                let title = valueDictionary["Title"]
                let location = valueDictionary["Location"]
                let date = valueDictionary["Date"]
                let description = valueDictionary["Description"]
                self.posts.insert(eventStruct(title: title, date: date, location: location, description: description), at: 0)
                self.tableview.reloadData()
            }
        })

    }

    /////////////////////////     Table View Content     \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        let label1 = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
        label1.text = posts[indexPath.row].title
        let label2 = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
        label2.text = posts[indexPath.row].location
        let label3 = cell.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel
        label3.text = posts[indexPath.row].date
        return cell
    }

    func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: eventStruct) {
        let secondViewController = segue.destination as? EventViewController
        secondViewController?.data = sender
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetails", sender: posts[indexPath.row])
    }
    /////////////////////////////////////\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
}

struct eventStruct {
    let title: String!
    let date: String!
    let location: String!
    let description: String!


}
```

Here is the `DetailsViewController` that should display the title of the different option that is selected in the previous `tableView`:

```
import UIKit

class EventViewController: UIViewController {

    var data: eventStruct?
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print (data?.title as Any)
        self.titleLabel.text = self.data?.title

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

The problem is that instead of displaying the title that should be stored inside of the struct variable, a `nil` value is returned all the time.

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I've tried to follow all the suggestions that were made but nothing works.

Comment: see this  : https://teamtreehouse.com/community/can-swift-structs-have-optional-stored-properties

Comment: I have also initialize the parameters in my struct. Still cannot retrieve the data

Comment: can you verify `let secondViewController = segue.destination as? EventViewController` is succeeding, your "showDetails" segue is correct and indeed pointing to an assigned `EventViewController` on the storyboard?

Comment: Is not executing at all the `prepareForSegue` function. Is executing only this command: `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetails", sender: indexPath)
    }`

Comment: your `prepareForSegue` function should be `override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` to conform to the protocol. You can then type cast the sender to `eventStruct` inside the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `prepareForSegue` must override the UIViewController method which is

```
func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
```

Therefore your method in `NewsfeedViewController` should be

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let secondViewController = segue.destination as? EventViewController
    secondViewController?.data = sender as? eventStruct
}
```

it would also be a good idea to add some error checking

Comment: now if I print the data received by the second view controller I get this message: `nil
Optional(RUC_App_1_0.eventStruct(title: Study group, date: 2017-06-12, location: House1, description: sudho ifoisjfoij owuh owunoiun oiwn ovin oiwn ioeunwofini))
2017-06-15 21:03:44.385 RUC-App 1.0[48189:5741258] Warning: Attempt to present <RUC_App_1_0.EventViewController: 0x7f874c129dd0> on <RUC_App_1_0.NewsfeedViewController: 0x7f874a529420> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

Comment: The window hierarchy warning can depend on whether you are using NavigationControllers or various other information. [This may be relevant](http://techqa.info/programming/question/36402149/Attempt-to-present-controller-whose-view-is-not-in-the-window-hierarchy) or [this](http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-avoid-whose-view-is-not-in-the-window-hierarchy-error-when-presenting-a-uiviewcontroller/), or you can ask a separate question, as the data passing was the topic of this one.

Answer (score 1):

Change property in `EventViewCotntroller` from `AnyData` to `eventStruct` like:

```
var data: eventStruct?
```

and then in table controller:

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: eventStruct?) {

    let secondViewController = segue.destination as? EventViewController
    secondViewController?.data = sender

}
```

keep in mind that `eventStruct` has to be out of yout TableViewControlle class scope:

```
class TableViewController {
// controller logic 
}

struct eventStruct {
// struct body
}
```

Comment: I cannot declare the property `eventStruct?` because it says that is undefined.

Comment: move eventStruct out of Table View Controller scope

Comment: I have attached all the code that I use in the two classes. I've tried your solution but still doesn't work. Can you see any problem in the code? Thank you.

Comment: The second part is not correct. The ‘prepareForSegue’ method must override the UIViewController method to be called. ‘sender’ type must stay as ‘Any?’

Comment: I missed this .

Answer (score 1):

Try folllowing

**In EventViewController**

```
var propertStruct : (Any)? = nil
```

**While passing data**

```
secondViewController.propertStruct =   eventStruct(title : "", date : "", location: "", description: "")
```

**Output**

[image]

**Console while assign**

[image]

**In SecondViewController**

[image]

**OR**

you need to pass indexpath in prepareforSegue

```
 performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetails", sender: indexPath)

func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any) {
            let indexPath = sender as! IndexPath
            let eventStruct =  post[indexPath.row]
            let secondViewController = segue.destination as? EventViewController
            secondViewController?.data = sender as AnyObject

        }
```

Comment: is propertStruct getting nil ?

Comment: Yes. I print it just before sending with performSegue, and is printing ‘nil’.

Comment: I have attached all my code for the two classes. I really cannot see the problem. And I do not get any error.

Comment: why did you declared constructor init(title: String!, date:String!, location:String!, description:String!){ self.title = title ?

Comment: it was just one example that I have found on the internet.. also without that it doesn't work.

Comment: not you dont need . you can do without  that constructor...comment that or remove that.

Comment: see my screenshots which i mentioned

Answer (score 0):

**First View Controller**

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            if indexPath.row == 0
            {
                let objstory = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
            objstory.strd = imageView.image
            _ = self.navigationController?.pushViewController(objstory, animated: true)

            }
        }
```

**SecondViewController**

```
 var strd:UIImage!
@IBOutlet weak var imgprof: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imgprof.image = strd


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```